# IE10 HTML Rendering, works with IP, but not with Configured domain

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-10

I am working on a simple website on my local system configured with IIS on Windows 8. My system is in ADS also. I have the following navigation bar in my html.

```
<div class="bar">
    <ul class="navul">
        <li class="navli sp"><a class="toplinks" href="#">Home</a></li
        ><li class="navli"><a class="toplinks" href="#">Register</a></li
        ><li class="navli"><a class="toplinks" href="#">Privacy</a></li
        ><li class="navli"><a class="toplinks" href="#">Disclaimer</a></li
        ><li class="navli"><a class="toplinks" href="#">Terms</a></li
        ><li class="navli"><a class="toplinks" href="#">About</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And the corresponding CSS is

```
.bar
{
height:50px;
background:url('../img/nav.jpg');
-webkit-border-radius: 4px;
-ms-border-radius: 4px;
-moz-border-radius: 4px;
-o-border-radius: 4px;
border-radius: 4px;
}
.navul
{
list-style:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
.navli
{
display:inline-block;
font-size: 24px;
font-family: Georgia Verdana;
text-align: center;
border-right: 1px solid;
border-color: #EEE;
color:white;
height:50px;
}
.sp
{
-webkit-border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
-moz-border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
-ms-border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
-o-border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
}
.navli:hover
{
background:#040;
}
.toplinks
{
display:inline-block;
text-decoration: none;
padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
margin:0;
color:#E1E1E1;
}
.toplinks:visited
{
color:#E1E1E1;
}
.toplinks:hover
{
color:white;
}
```

The problem I faced is that, when I use my IP or localhost or even directly open the html file, IE10 displays as expected, but when I open with the domain, it displays wrong.

The below format is displayed using IP

[image: IE 10]

and when I access using the domain, I obtain the following.

[image: IE 10 invalid]

Please suggest any work-around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In IE, hit the alt key once in order to show the menu bar across the top (like the olden days). Click Tools > Compatibility View Settings.

You might have the box "Display intranet sites in Compatibility View" box checked. This would explain the differing behavior when viewing the site locally.